# In HTML5, should the main navigation be inside or outside the <header> element?

Tags: html

In HTML5, I know that `<nav>` can be used either inside or outside the page's masthead  `<header>` element. For websites having both secondary and main navigation, it seems common to include the secondary navigation as a `<nav>` element inside the masthead `<header>` element with the main navigation as a `<nav>` element outside the masthead `<header>` element.  However, if the website lacks secondary navigation, it appears common to include the main navigation in a `<nav>` element within the masthead `<header>` element.

If I follow these examples, my content structure will be based on the inclusion or exclusion of secondary navigation. This introduces a coupling between the content and the style that feels unnecessary and unnatural.

Is there a better way so that I'm not moving the main navigation from inside to outside the masthead `<header>` element based on the inclusion or exclusion of secondary navigation?

### Main and Secondary Navigation Example

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <!-- Secondary Navigation inside <header> -->
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <h1>Website Title</h1>
</header>
<nav>
    <!-- Main Navigation outside <header> -->
    <ul>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[OnlineDegrees.org](http://onlinedegrees.org) is an example site that follows the above pattern.

[image]

### Main Only Navigation Example

```
<header>
    <h1>Website Title</h1>
    <nav>
        <!-- Main Navigation inside <header> -->
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

[Keyzo.co.uk](http://keyzo.co.uk/) is an example site that follows the above pattern.

[image]

### Excerpts from *Introducing HTML5* — Added on 02-Feb-11, 7:38 AM

[*Introducing HTML5*](http://amzn.com/0321687299) by Bruce Lawson and Remy Sharp has this to say about the subject:

> The header can also contain navigation. This can be very useful for site-wide navigation, especially on template-driven sites where the whole of the `<header>` element could come from a template file.
>
> Of course, it's not required that the `<nav>` be in the `<header>`.
>
> If depends largely on whether you believe the site-wide navigation belongs in the site-wide header and also pragmatic considerations about ease of styling.

Based on that last sentence, it appears that Bruce Lawson—author of the chapter those excerpts are from—admits that "pragmatic considerations about ease of styling" yield a coupling between the content and the style.

Comment: It depends *entirely* on your website's design. Take twitter for example, their Homepage (the page you see before you've logged-in), has no top navigation. All their "main menu" stuff is at the bottom of the page. Now, I don't know about you - but I wouldn't go calling that a header...

Answer (score 139, accepted):

It's completely up to you. You can either put them in the header or not, as long as the elements within them are internal navigation elements only (i.e. don't link to external sites such as a twitter or facebook account) then it's fine.

They tend to get placed in a header simply because that's where navigation often goes, but it's not set in stone.

You can read more about it at [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/).

Comment: Why do you state that "as long as the elements within them are internal navigation elements only (i.e. don't link to external sites such as a twitter or facebook account) then it's fine."?

Comment: @Matthew because the nav element is for navigation around that site only. I was just being clear is all.

Comment: @MatthewRankin What a shock it would be to click on an anchor inside of a `<nav>` element, only to be sent to a new page with entirely different navigation. For anchors to external sites with no true relationship to your own, also remember the `rel="nofollow"` attribute for links.

Comment: I know this is old... What about links to subdomains? For example a website that has different sites (presentation site, service site, auth site, etc...), they all have different structure. What I'm doing is placing that link inside the `<nav>` element but not inside the `<ul>` element, styling it in a way that's not part of the main navigation list. With the exception being the mobile version, the link has to appear in the same list... Anyways the button is descriptive enough to know you're going somewhere else...

Answer (score 12):

I do not like putting the *nav* in the *header*. My reasoning is:

**Logic**

The *header* contains introductory information about the document. The *nav* is a menu that links to other documents. To my mind this means that the content of the *nav* belongs to the site rather than the document. An exception would be if the NAV held forward links.

**Accessibility**

I like to put menus at the end of the source code rather than the start. I use CSS to send it to the top of a computer screen or leave it at the end for text-speech browsers and small screens. This avoids the need for skip-links.

Comment: keep in mind that skip links give the OPTION to skip the menu, while putting at the end doesn't give the option of not skipping (i.e. navigating) - thus you'd be forced to wait until the end to be able to navigate properly, right?

Comment: To continue on @julix's point, placing the nav at the end, but rendering it at the beginning will make it awkward for sighted users tabbing through the document.

Comment: `<nav>` is a semantic element, meaning that its purpose is defined by it's contextual placement. You can have one `<nav>` for the site navigation and another `<nav>` for the page navigation. It doesn't _have_ to be only for site navigation.

Answer (score 9):

@IanDevlin is correct. [MDN's rules say the following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML_sections_and_outlines):

"The HTML Header Element "" defines a page header — typically containing the logo and name of the site and possibly a horizontal menu..."

The word "possibly" there is key. It goes on to say that the header doesn't necessarily need to be a site header. For instance you could include a "header" on a pop-up modal or on other modular parts of the document where there is a header and it would be helpful for a user on a screen reader to know about it.

It terms of the implicit use of NAV you can use it anywhere there is grouped site navigation, although it's usually omitted from the "footer" section for mini-navs / important site links.

Really it comes down to personal / team choice. Decide what you and your team feel is more semantic and more important and the try to be consistent. For me, if the nav is inline with the logo and the main site's "h1" then it makes sense to put it in the "header" but if you have a different design choice then decide on a case by case basis.

Most importantly check out the docs and be sure if you choose to omit or include you understand why you are making that particular decision.

Answer (score 9):

I think the simpliest way to answer this is to check the MDN Web Docs and other web standards sites.
[image: MDN Web Docs nav element is inside the header element]

Answer (score 6):

It's a little unclear whether you're asking for opinions, eg. "it's common to do xxx" or an actual rule, so I'm going to lean in the direction of rules.

The examples you cite seem based upon the examples in the [spec for the nav element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-nav-element). Remember that the spec keeps getting tweaked and the rules are sometimes convoluted, so I'd venture many people might tend to just do what's given rather than interpret. You're showing two *separate* examples with different behavior, so there's only so much you can read into it. Do either of those sites also have the opposing sub/nav situation, and if so how do they handle it?

Most importantly, though, there's nothing in the spec saying either is **the** way to do it. One of the goals with HTML5 was to be [very clear](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#headings-and-sections)[this for comparison] about semantics, requirements, etc. so the omission is worth noting. As far as I can see, the examples are independent of each other and equally valid within their own context of layout requirements, etc.

Having the nav's source position be conditional is kind of silly(another red flag). Just pick a method and go with it.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on what @JoshuaMaddox said, in the MDN Learning Area, under the "Introduction to HTML" section, the [Document and website structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Document_and_website_structure) sub-section says (bold/emphasis is by me):

> ## Header
>
> Usually a big strip across the top with a big heading and/or logo.
> This is where the main common information about a website usually
> stays from one webpage to another.
>
> ## Navigation bar
>
> Links to the site's main sections; usually represented by menu
> buttons, links, or tabs. Like the header, this content usually remains
> consistent from one webpage to another — having an inconsistent
> navigation on your website will just lead to confused, frustrated
> users. **Many web designers consider the navigation bar to be part of
> the header rather than a individual component, but that's not a
> requirement; in fact some also argue that having the two separate is
> better for accessibility, as screen readers can read the two features
> better if they are separate**.

Comment: I want to agree that a `<nav>` that is structured shallow in a page may be more accessible than a `<nav>` that is nested deeper. However, on what basis is that judgement being made? Screen readers are going to home in on `<nav>` and `<a>` tags, anyway. The important factor is the structural order of the HTML. Next up, responsiveness. Does making the primary `<nav>` (or any `<nav>`) a direct child of `<body>` make it easier to manipulate? Is that valid HTML? A `<nav>` is *sectioning content*, and thus is a natural fit to live within a *sectioning root*, like `<body>`. See W3C HTML5

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

#### there is no right or wrong. It depends on what you build.

This is a question that every web developer asks himself at some point. I had asked myself the question several times. To answer this question, I looked at the source code of Stackoverflow. And SO has the nav tag inside the header tag.

Which is absolutely right here, because if you look at the structure of the view of the top bar, it quickly becomes clear that this is the right way to go. Here you can simply work with the flexbox design. Which in turn would only work with a superordinate tag if both tags were not nested. Which would unnecessarily bleach the DOM. like:

```html
<div class="flex">
  <header></header>
  <nav></nav>
</div>
```

On the other hand, there are headers that are simply a large image with a logo inside. Or a whole line with the logo. Here it doesn't matter whether the nav tag is above or below the header tag.

**Conclusion:** The tags only have a semantic meaning and are not a specification for a template structure. You build the template according to your ideas or the expectations of the users.

Both cases are right!

```html
<!-- case 1 -->
<body>
 <header></header>
 <nav></nav>
 <main></main>
</body>

<!-- case 2 -->
<body>
 <header>
   <nav></nav>
 </header>
 <main></main>
</body>
```