# text under header with Html and Css

Tags: html, css

I have the following code, which displays a header with in each page of my website:

```css
#header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: burlywood;
  color: beige;
  border-style: groove;
}
#register {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>About HatSpace</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/about_style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div>
      <h1>HatSpace</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="register">
      <form>
        <input style="width: 500px;" type="text" placeholder="Search the Website">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>Log in</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Sign in</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Now, how can I add these three texts right beneath it, so that they will be included in the header div too. I've tried various ways, but it rearranges my header...I just want easier navigation for the user, so that when they click home, they go back home no matter which page they are since it's always part of the header.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: use bootstrap it's better for header and menu and good for responsive

Comment: I know, but I want to learn css html

Comment: then create the two rows in your header add the logo, search box and login button in top row and use html5 nav tag use this link to read http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/

Comment: your question answer is right here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870955/in-html5-should-the-main-navigation-be-inside-or-outside-the-header-element/4872533#4872533

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your first row in another div inside the header and give it the flex properties you're giving the whole header now. Then make another div with the same flex properties after with the three texts. For example:

```css
#part1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#part2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="part1">
    <div>
      <h1>HatSpace</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="register">
      <form>
        <input style="width: 500px;" type="text" placeholder="Search the Website">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>Log in</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Sign in</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="part 2">
    // About us, etc...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#header {
 background-color: burlywood;
  color: beige;
  border-style: groove;
}
.header-top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
 
}

.header-bottom{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
text-indent: 1rem;
}

#register {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>About HatSpace</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/about_style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
  <div class="header-top">
    <div>
      <h1>HatSpace</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="register">
      <form>
        <input style="width: 500px;" type="text" placeholder="Search the Website">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>Log in</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Sign in</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header-bottom">
  <div>text1</div>
  <div>text2</div>
  <div>text3</div>
  <div>
  </div>
```