# Should <nav> be within <header> and can both be their own container?

Tags: html, css

Apologies if my terminology isn't correct. This is my first time posting on here and I'm relatively new to coding HTML and CSS.

In my header tag I've only added the title of my website. I put my nav tag and links as a separate section below the header.

Is this the proper way to set everything up? Or is it more efficient to have the `<nav>` within the header?

Also do I need to have a container within `<header>` and `<nav>` or can those tags be their own container?

Here's the code I've written:

```
    <header>
        <div class="headercontainer">
        <h1 class="title">welcome</h1>
        </div>
    </header>

    <nav>
        <div class="navcontainer">
        <a href="#" class="navlink">link1</a>
        <a href="#" class="navlink">link2</a>
        <a href="#" class="navlink">link3</a>
        <a href="#" class="navlink">link4</a>    
        <a href="#" class="navlink">clink5</a>
        </div>       
    </nav>
```

I'm just looking for an explanation on what is best to do

Comment: If your `nav` is conceptually part of the header, include it in `header`

Answer (score 0):

You can do either inside the header or outside.
For styling you do not need a container inside the nav, just use either an id or class directly on the nav.

See [In HTML5, should the main navigation be inside or outside the <header> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870955/in-html5-should-the-main-navigation-be-inside-or-outside-the-header-element)